# How to access multiple MongoDB collections from state using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

### Scenario

To use a many-to-many relationship I am trying to read documents from different collections within a single MongoDB database. I have a backend called `server.js` which "reads" the collection locations from files `university.js` and `faculty.js`. I made two separate `router.get` methods for them. Each of them individually works, and I am trying to add the 2nd `router.get` method into a different "state" called "Faculties".

### Example files

`faculty.js` (analogous to `universities.js`)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create another collection
const FacultyCollection = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    amountOfBuildings: Number
  },
  { collection: 'faculties' },
  { timestamps: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true}
);

// export the new Schema so we could modify it using Node.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("faculties", FacultyCollection);
```

`router.get`.. method (analogous to universities)

```
router.get('/getFaculties', (req, res) => {
  Faculties.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});
```

`App.js` `state` and `getFaculties`:

```
state = {
        data: [],
        id: 0,
        message: null,
        intervalIsSet: false,
        idToDelete: null,
        idToUpdate: null,
        objectToUpdate: null,
    };

faculties = {
        data: [],
        id: 0,
        message: null,
        intervalIsSet: false,
        idToDelete: null,
        idToUpdate: null,
        objectToUpdate: null,
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDataFromDb();
        if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 5000);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
        }
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            clearInterval(this.state.intervalIsSet);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: null });
        }
    }
    
    getDataFromDb = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties')
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((res) => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
    };
```

Example `render` to display the data from the faculty collection:

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { faculties } = this.faculties;
    return (
      <div>
        {/*This folds the data of the state into an array with university names*/}
        dat.name={data.map((dat) => dat.name)}

        {/*This is intended to fold the data of the faculties into an array with faculty names*/}
        dat.name={faculties.map((dat) => dat.name)}
     </div>
  );
}
```

### Question

How can I store and read the the names of the `faculty` collection (from the/a state) (on the same page) when I also display the university names from the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Understanding

The solution was not to make a copy of the `state` with name `faculties`, but to add the "property/field" `faculties` within the state. Additionally when one says:

```
.then((res) => this.setState({ faculties: res.data }));
```

It means it sets the property `faculties` within the state, but it will not throw an error/warning if that property does not exist when you try to put data into it anyway.

### code

The complete working solution can be accessed [here](https://github.com/a-t-0/living-lab-app-repo/commit/7bda2f6c9b6e02da85177dc70ace8b18d269bce3). To prevent dependencies in answer here is the working code:
`faculties.js`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create another collection
const FacultyCollection = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    amountOfBuildings: Number
  },
  { collection: 'faculties' },
  { timestamps: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true}
);

// export the new Schema so we could modify it using Node.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("faculties", FacultyCollection);**
```

`universities.js`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create another collection
const UniversityCollection = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    temperature: Number
  },
  { collection: 'universities' },
  { timestamps: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true}
);

// export the new Schema so we could modify it using Node.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("university", UniversityCollection);
```

`server.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const Faculties = require('./faculties');
const Universities = require('./universities');

const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();

const dbRoute = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/education';

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));

router.get('/getFaculties', (req, res) => {
  Faculties.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});

router.get('/getUniversities', (req, res) => {
  Universities.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});

router.post('/putData', (req, res) => {
  let data = new Faculties();

  console.log(req.body);

  const { name, temperature } = req.body;
  data.name = name;
  data.temperature = temperature;
  data.save((err) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

// append /api for our http requests
app.use('/api', router);

// launch our backend into a port
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

`app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var storeArray;

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        universities: [],
        faculties: [],
        id: 0,
        message: null,
        intervalIsSet: false,
        idToDelete: null,
        idToUpdate: null,
        objectToUpdate: null,
    };
        
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUniversities();
        if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            let interval = setInterval(this.getUniversities, 5000);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
        }
        
        this.getFaculties();
        if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            let interval = setInterval(this.getFaculties, 5000);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
        }
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            clearInterval(this.state.intervalIsSet);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: null });
        }
    }
    
    getUniversities = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getUniversities')
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((res) => this.setState({ universities: res.data }));
    };
    
    
    getFaculties= () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties')
                .then((data) => data.json())
                //set property "faculties" within the state" (won't throw error if you haven't defined property "faculties" within state".
                .then((res) => this.setState({ faculties: res.data })); 
    };
    
    
    // This transforms the data object property temperature into an array!
    // Source: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d
    getArrayOfOneElementType(data) {
        var officersIds = [];
        data.forEach(function (data) {officersIds.push(data.temperature);})   
        console.log(officersIds[2]);
        return officersIds;
    }
    
    // This transforms the data object property temperature into an array!
    // Source: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d
    getSingleEntry(data) {
        var officersIds = [];
        data.forEach(function (data) {officersIds.push(data.temperature);})   
        console.log(officersIds[2]);
        return officersIds[2];
    }
    
    // This function adds an option to the dropdownbox.
    addOption(){
        var inputElemAdd = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");        
        selectBox[0].label = "Wrote 0";
        selectBox[2].label = "Wrote 2";
        selectBox[3] = new Option('hi, added last label', 'id0',false,false); // add option
    }
    
    // This function adds an option to the dropdownbox using an array element of a query on the MongoDB.
    
    doSomething(h){
        alert("Hello world")
    }

    sayHello(arr) { 
        var inputElemAdd = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");        
        var i
        var newArr = this.filterUndefineds(arr);
        
        // set length of dropdownbox to incoming array
        selectBox.length = newArr.length;
        
        // assign arrays
        for (i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
            selectBox[i].label = newArr[i];
        }
    }
    
    // Filter undefined values from an array
    filterUndefineds(arr){
        var i
        var newArr = [];
        
        // only copy the non-undefined values from incoming array to newArr
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
                newArr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return newArr;
    }

    
  render() {
    const { universities } = this.state;
    const { faculties } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      
        {/*This is a table on the website*/}
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>temperature</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {universities.length <= 0
            ?   <tr><td colSpan="9">no data available</td></tr>
            : universities.map((dat) => (
              
                  <tr>
                  <td>{dat.name}</td> 
                  <td>{dat.temperature}</td>
                  </tr>               
              ))}
          </tbody>   
        </table>
        
        
        <br></br>
        {/*This folds the data into a data temperature array*/}
        dat.temperature={universities.map((dat) => dat.temperature)}
        dat.universityName={universities.map((dat) => dat.name)}
        
        <br></br>
        {/*This folds the data into a data temperature array*/}
        dat.name={faculties.map((dat) => dat.name)}
        
        {/*This folds the data into a data_id array (for all documnts in collection datas)*/}
        <br></br>
        dat.id={universities.map((dat) => dat._id)}
        
       {/*This calls a function that puts the data into a data_id array (for all documnts in collection datas)*/}
        <br></br>
        arrayOfTemp = {this.getArrayOfOneElementType(universities)}
                
        {/*This calls a function that gets a single element of a document in the collection datas)*/}
        <br></br>
        singleelement = {this.getSingleEntry(universities)}
        
        
        {/* Passing an array within the html (declare variable storeArray at top of script, use <script> to hide the output))*/}
        <br></br> 
        <script>
            {storeArray = this.getArrayOfOneElementType(universities)}
        </script>
        StoredArray={storeArray}
        
        <br></br> 
        {/*Dropdownbox*/}
        {/*Source: https://memorynotfound.com/dynamically-add-remove-options-select-javascript<br></br>*/}
        <select id="dynamic-select">
                <option value="1">one</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
                <option value="3">three</option>
        </select>
        
        <br></br>       
        {/*Add an element to the dropdownbox (must include function "addOption" above html in this App.js to make it work)*/}
        <button onClick={this.addOption}>add item</button> {/*// remove the brackets to make it happen at onclick*/}
            
        <br></br> 
        {/* Set fill the dropdownbox with array from MongoDB query*/}
        {/*<button onClick={() => this.sayHello('James')}>Greet</button>*/}
        <button onClick={() => this.sayHello(storeArray)}>Greet</button>    
            
        <br></br>   

      </div>
    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### Conclusion

Every time you want to add/access a (nother/new) collection from a certain dataset, create a separate link/url for it in the server, and add the property (=for example the collection name) to the state in `app.js`. Then write a get method in the `app.js` that assigns the data retrieved from the new  url from the `server.js` to the new property in the state.